# Hiding api model properies with swagger

Tags: java, rest, swagger

I currently have several APIs that share common objects. In some cases, I want to hide certain properties of these common objects when generating the swagger documentation. For instance, let's say I have a simple class:

```
public class Person {
  private String forename;
  private String surname;
  private int age;

  /* getters and setters with annotations here... */
}
```

For some APIs, I want the age field to appear in the swagger documentation but in other APIs I don't.

I don't want to use the `hidden` attribute of the `@ApiModelProperty` annotation as this will hide the property for all APIs. I can see there is an `access` attribute which I could use with my own filter class that extends `SwaggerSpecFilter`.

How can I do this by implementing the `isPropertyAllowed` method of this interface? There does not seem to be any parameter in that method that I can use to find out which Api is using the Model and property.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to implement this by having all my API classes have a 'Filter' class that will add/remove/edit any properties from the API models like so:

```
public class MyApiFilter implements SwaggerFilterIF {

@Override
public void filter(Swagger swagger) {
  Map<String, Model> definitions = swagger.getDefinitions();

  // remove 'age' from 'Person'
  Model model = definitions.get("Person");
  model.getProperties().remove("age");
}
```

This is then referenced in the API class:

```
@Api
@Path("/myapi")
public class MyApi implements SwaggerApiIF {
  public MyApi () {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public SwaggerFilterIF getFilter() {
    return new MyApiFilter();
  }
}
```

I then have a servlet to generate the API documentation for every API that I can access individually. In this servlet, I call the `filter` method on the 'Filter' class for the API which will filter the swagger definition as required:

```
for (final SwaggerApiIF api : apis) {
  final Swagger swagger = new Reader(new Swagger(), config).read(api.getClass());
  api.getFilter().filter(swagger);
}
```